# Adding SOAP:HEADER username and password with WSE 3.0

Tags: c#, web-services, ws-security, wse3.0

I have successfully created a WS client that works correctly when NOT using authentication.

However, the server (WebSphere) now requires adding a ws-security username token, and I'm having a hard time doing this.  The resulting SOAP message is supposed to look something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
  xmlns:ns="http://foo.bar/1.0"
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.witsml.org/schemas/140"   
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

  <soapenv:Header>

    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>foo</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">bar</wsse:Password>    
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">foooooobar==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2010-01-25T13:09:24.860Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>

  </soapenv:Header>

  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:fooBar>...</ns:fooBar>
  </soapenv:Body>
```

I've downloaded and installed Microsoft's WSE 3.0 SDK and added a reference to the DLL in my Visual Studio 2005 project.

I now have access to the Microsoft.Web.Services3.* namespaces, but I'm currently stumped on how to proceed.

The client code has been generated automatically by a web reference, so I only do a minor amount of work to send the message to the server *unauthenticated*:

```
WS.FooResultHttpService ws = new WS.FooResultHttpService();
ws.Url = "http://foo.bar.baz";
ws.SendSomething(message);
```

I've just begun to investigate using `Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameTokenManager`, but so far I haven't been able to get anything up and running.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, as I can't seem to find any good recipes on the net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it working, unfortunately before reading [wsanville's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139190/adding-soapheader-username-and-password-with-wse-3-0/2139480#2139480).

To help others, I'm posting all the steps I needed to do to get it working with Visual Studio 2005:

- Install [WSE 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en), choose *custom* and select everything
- Read [Implementing direct authentication with username token in WSE 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480575.aspx) for hints
- Relaunch Visual Studio 2005, now right-click on your project in the solution explorer, and you should have a *WSE Settings 3.0* menu item and use that if you want to.
- Update your web references, this should create a new HTTP web service proxy class, with a different name, e.g. `YourWsNameHttpServiceWse`.  This is essentially the same as running [wsewsdl3.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx)
- Use this new class, and you should have access to WSE methods and properties, such as `SetClientCredential`.

I ended up doing almost everything in code, instead of relying on the config-files that are built with my C# DLL.  The code ended up looking like this:

```
FooBarHttpServiceWse wse = new FooBarHttpServiceWse();

wse.SetClientCredential(new UsernameToken(
    "username",
    "password",
    PasswordOption.SendPlainText));

wse.SetPolicy(new FooBarPolicy());
wse.CallSomeServerFunction(yourRequest)
```

I created my own policy, which looked like this:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Design;

// ...

public class FooBarPolicy : Policy
{
    public FooBarPolicy()
    {
        this.Assertions.Add(new UsernameOverTransportAssertion());
    }
}
```

Finally, the WebSphere server responded that *A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present*, and inspecting the outgoing message (using the nice tool [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)) I saw the SOAP fault from the server indicated that the Action header was missing.

I tried in vain to set the `wsa:Action` element myself:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing;

// ...

wse.RequestSoapContext.Addressing.Action = new Action("CallSomeServerFunction");
```

The problem was that even if I set an action, when it was sent over the wire, it was empty.  Turned out I had to open the WSE proxy class and edit an attribute there:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(
    "---Edit this to set wsa:Action---", 
    Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, 
    ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
// ...
public SomeServerFunction(...)
```

After that, it all worked out nicely.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure your proxy class inherits from `Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol`.

You can do this either by changing the proxy class itself, or by generating it via the command line using [wsewsdl3.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx) with the `/type:webClient` switch.

You can then pass the credentials like this:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services3;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security;
.
.
.
WS.FooResultHttpService ws = new WS.FooResultHttpService();
ws.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(new UsernameToken("blah", "blah", PasswordOption.SendPlainText));
```

This is what I've done in the past to get WSE3.0 going in Studio 2008. Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 very useful. Had issue generating proxy using WseWsdl3.exe on VS2010, This was fixed by adding entry in registry. Add string key named "sdkInstallRootv2.0" at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\ with value "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A"