# How can we get the all childs value from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml

Here is a XML file :

```
<AppBuilderProject>
    <Name>Project1</Name>
    <AppBuilderForms>
        <AppBuilderForm>
            <Title>Form1</Title>
            <AppBuilderFormObjects>
                <CheckMarkObject>
                    <Name>subscribeCheckmark</Name>
                    <Label>Subscribe</Label>
                    <IsChecked>1</IsChecked>
                </CheckMarkObject>
                <DateTimeObject>
                    <Name>dateOfBirth</Name>
                    <Label>Date of Birth</Label>
                </DateTimeObject>
                <LocationObject>
                    <Name>mapLocation</Name>
                    <Label>Any Location</Label>
                    <Longitude>1.23453</Longitude>
                    <Latitude>1.2345</Latitude>
                </LocationObject>
                <SwitchObject>
                    <Name>newsletterSwitch</Name>
                    <Label>Receive Newsletter</Label>
                    <IsChecked>1</IsChecked>
                </SwitchObject>
                <TextViewObject>
                    <Name>detailTextView</Name>
                    <Value>Details</Value>
                </TextViewObject>
                <TextFieldObject>
                    <Name>nameTextField</Name>
                    <Label>Name</Label>
                    <Value>name</Value>
                </TextFieldObject>
                <PhotoPickerObject>
                    <Name>photoPicker</Name>
                    <Label>Pick Photo</Label>
                </PhotoPickerObject>
                <SpinWheelPickerObject>
                    <Name>comboBox</Name>
                    <Label>Countries</Label>
                    <SpinWheelPickerColumns>
                        <SpinWheelPickerColumnObject>
                            <Name>name</Name>
                            <Label>Name</Label>
                            <SpinWheelPickerItems>
                                <SpinWheelPickerItemObject>
                                    <Name>Pakistan</Name>
                                    <Label>Pakistan</Label>
                                </SpinWheelPickerItemObject>
                                <SpinWheelPickerItemObject>
                                    <Name>United Arab Emirates</Name>
                                    <Label>United Arab Emirates</Label>
                                </SpinWheelPickerItemObject>
                            </SpinWheelPickerItems>
                        </SpinWheelPickerColumnObject>
                        <SpinWheelPickerColumnObject>
                            <Name>code</Name>
                            <Label>Code</Label>
                            <SpinWheelPickerItems>
                                <SpinWheelPickerItemObject>
                                    <Name>+92</Name>
                                    <Label>+92</Label>
                                </SpinWheelPickerItemObject>
                                <SpinWheelPickerItemObject>
                                    <Name>+971</Name>
                                    <Label>+971</Label>
                                </SpinWheelPickerItemObject>
                            </SpinWheelPickerItems>
                        </SpinWheelPickerColumnObject>
                    </SpinWheelPickerColumns>
                </SpinWheelPickerObject>
            </AppBuilderFormObjects>
        </AppBuilderForm>
    </AppBuilderForms>
</AppBuilderProject>
```

and i want to get all the values.
And i use this code to find all the value in my XML:

this code only reads the root node only:

```
XmlDocument DOC = new XmlDocument();
//  DOC.RemoveAll();
DOC.Load("C:\\Users\\DIGITEL EYE SYSTEM\\Desktop\\response.xml");
XmlNode firstnode = DOC.SelectSingleNode("AppBuilderProject");
Project.Name = firstnode["Name"].InnerText;
XmlNode secondnode = DOC.SelectSingleNode("AppBuilderProject/AppBuilderForm");
XmlNodeList controlingnode = secondnode.SelectNodes("Title");



XmlNodeList ParentNode = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("AppBuilderProject");

foreach (XmlNode AllNodes in ParentNode)
{
    Project.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;


    if (AllNodes.ChildNodes == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("AppBuilderForms"))
    {
        //  Project.Forms = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("");
        // String sb = AllNodes["Forms"].InnerText;
    }
    XmlNodeList checkmarknode = DOC.GetElementsByTagName("CheckMarkObject");

    if (checkmarknode.Item(0).InnerText == "Name")
    {
        checkmark.Name = checkmarknode[0].InnerText;
    }
    else if (checkmarknode.Item(1).InnerText == "Label")
    {
        checkmark.Label = checkmarknode[1].InnerText;
    }
    // if (AllNodes.ChildNodes == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("CheckMarkObject"))
    //  {
    //     checkmark.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;


    //   checkmark.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
    // checkmark.IsChecked = AllNodes["IsChecked"].InnerText;
    // }

    if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("DateTimeObject"))
    {
        DateTime.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        DateTime.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
    }

    if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("LocationObject"))
    {
        Location.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        Location.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
        Location.Longitude = AllNodes["Longitude"].InnerText;
        Location.Latitude = AllNodes["Latitude"].InnerText;
    }

    if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("SwitchObject"))
    {
        Switch.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        Switch.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
        // Switch.IsChecked = AllNodes["IsChecked"].InnerText;
    }

    if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("TextViewObject"))
    {
        TextView.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        TextView.Value = AllNodes["Value"].InnerText;
    }

    if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("TextFieldObject"))
    {
        TextField.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        TextField.Value = AllNodes["Value"].InnerText;
    }

    if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("PhotoPickerObject"))
    {
        PhotoPicker.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        PhotoPicker.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
    }

    if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("SpinWheelPickerObject"))
    {
        SpinWheelPicker.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
        SpinWheelPicker.Label = AllNodes["Label"].InnerText;
        // SpinWheelPicker.Columns = AllNodes["Columns"].InnerText;
    }
```

but it get only root node value so please tell the solution. thanks

Comment: Does it have to use `XmlDocument`, or is it .Net 4.0 - in that case Linq-Xml will be easier?

Comment: @DaveShaw: yes it use XmlDocument and i use .Net 4.0 freamwork as well.

Comment: So, would a Linq-Xml solution be suitable?

Comment: @DaveShaw: i think this method is easy from Linq-XML. what you suggest.?

Comment: yes use Linq-XML, it would be more easy

Comment: @alliswell: can you send me the link or give a small example that how can i use this ?

Comment: you see the answer posted by me, Dave linked some urls.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LINQ2XML`..its way too simple and cool

It is a complete replacement to other `xml` api's

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml");
doc.Descendants("AppBuilderProject").Element("Name").Value;//name value
doc.Descendants("AppBuilderForms").Descendants("AppBuilderForm").Element("Title").Value;//title value
```

Comment: I agree, just my two pennies: 1. possible NullReferenceExceptions in this code (I understand that it only shows a concept, but OP may not be aware of that) 2. LINQ to XML is not recommended for big XML files, because it parses XML in its entirety instead of processing it sequentially. Again, I can see that the particular file the OP is dealing with is small, but nevertheless LINQ to XML is *not always* a good approach and thus it can't be used to replace other XML APIs completely, as you say

Answer (score 1):

In general, you won't want to navigate through an XmlDocument by regarding all elements as at the same level of hierarchy - Xml has a hierarchical structure which can contain complex relationships like 1:N, nesting, etc.

So instead of looping and writing code like

```
 if (ParentNode == DOC.GetElementsByTagName("SpinWheelPickerObject"))
 {
   SpinWheelPicker.Name = AllNodes["Name"].InnerText;
   ...
 }
```

With `XmlDocument` / `XmlNode`, it would be preferable to use Xpath to navigate to the element / attribute that you require, e.g.

```
   SpinWheelPicker.Name = 
     DOC.SelectSingleNode("/AppBuilderProject//SpinWheelPickerObject/Name")
        .InnerText;
```

**Edit**

To iterate through a 1:N relationship, you should use `foreach` to iterate over the collection, e.g.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in DOC.SelectNodes("//SpinWheelPickerItemObject"))
{
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Here we are also using the `//` shortcut to avoid walking through the hierarchy. Note however that this ignores the hierarchy - i.e. any element named `SpinWheelPickerItemObject` anywhere in the document will be included.

Comment: in some case, it is very necessary to apply loops.
e.g: AppBuilderForms look in XML. so what can i do for this ?

Comment: @StuartLC I ask a similar question, would you please check it, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247449/customize-xml-serialize-with-new-tags-and-attributes-and-root

Answer (score 0):

Using [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) / [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) it would be more easier, and also you can do linq very easily..

```
XElement xmlObject = XElement.Load(fileName);
var xDoc = xmlObject.Descendants("AppBuilderProject") //will return you all the elements
```

Comment: by this method can we get all the child nodes value ?

Comment: Returns a collection of the descendant elements for this document or element, in document order http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This LINQ can do the Job.The idea is to fetch all the XmlNodes and check if its of type Text.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("somedata.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    var Values = XElement.Load(fs).DescendantNodes()
                         .Where(item => item.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text);
}
```